# Get @@SERVERNAME from linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, linked-server, openrowset, exec

This seems like a basic question but I can't find any answers out there - I need to be able to get the server name/instance etc. from a linked server. I've tried a couple of things:

```
select <linked server>.@@SERVERNAME;
select <linked server>.SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName');
```

... but no joy. Any ideas?

This is `SQL 2008 R2` & `2014` (`2008R2` is the linked server)

EDIT: Errors are:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near
>   '@@SERVERNAME'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `OPENQUERY` [as explained in MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427(v=sql.105).aspx) to get the information of Linked server:

i.e using `OPENQUERY ( linked_server ,'query' )`

with something like below will give you server name using `sys.dm_exec_connections` dmv

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (
         linkedservername, 
         'SELECT
             @@SERVERNAME AS TargetServerName,
             SUSER_SNAME() AS ConnectedWith,
             DB_NAME() AS DefaultDB,
             client_net_address AS IPAddress
          FROM
              sys.dm_exec_connections
          WHERE
              session_id = @@SPID
        ')
```

Answer (score 11):

Some slightly shorter (and more natural, IMHO) approaches:

```
EXEC LinkedServer.[master].sys.sp_executesql N'SELECT @@VERSION;';
```

Or:

```
EXEC('SELECT @@VERSION;') AT LinkedServer;
```

I prefer the `sp_executesql` route because:

1. It will still allow for strongly-typed parameters, instead of dealing with all kinds of string concatenation, escaping of single quotes, etc.
2. It is easy to specify a particular database in that path, instead of having to put database prefixes on all the objects referenced in the query. And yes, you can define the database dynamically:

   ```
   DECLARE @db SYSNAME, @exec NVARCHAR(1024);
   SET @db = N'tempdb';
   SET @exec = N'LinkedServer.' + QUOTENAME(@db) + N'.sys.sp_executesql';
   EXEC @exec N'SELECT @@VERSION, DB_NAME();';
   ```

   And the linked server name, too, if need be:

   ```
   DECLARE @srv SYSNAME, @db SYSNAME, @exec NVARCHAR(1024);
   SET @srv = N'LinkedServer';
   SET @db = N'tempdb';
   SET @exec = QUOTENAME(@srv) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@db) + N'.sys.sp_executesql';
   EXEC @exec N'SELECT @@VERSION, DB_NAME();';
   ```

Answer (score 1):

There are easier ways to get at the server names of your linked servers.  You could query sys.sysservers or run EXEC sp_linkedservers to give you all the info you need on your local linked servers including the server name. Here's the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189519(v=sql.90).aspx) on sp_linkedservers if you want it.  While this doesn't necessarily answer the question of how to SELECT @@SERVERNAME remotely, it gets you that information.

Comment: This is exactly what I've done. `SELECT name FROM master.sys.servers where is_linked=1` I then loop through and dynamically get everything I need.

Comment: Well, let's not forget that the linked server could be defined by IP address, or a client network utility alias, or something that's masked by hosts file / DNS, etc. The way SQL Server routes to it is not necessarily the hostname.

Answer (score -2):

**Easiest Way** (SSMS)

You can't script it through openquery if you don't have permissions on the master database (nor should you).

From the object explorer

+Linked Objects

++Linked Servers

+++[Linked Server Name]

Left click the linked server name Script Linked Server As > Create To > New Query Editor Window

Look for @datasrc='linked server source here'

Voila!