# Setting a variable from a statement that starts with EXEC

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I am trying to get the Server Name from a LinkedServer and assign it to a variable.

From this question ([Get @@SERVERNAME from linked server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115201/get-servername-from-linked-server)), I found that either of these return the Server Name.

```
EXEC LinkedServer.[master].sys.sp_executesql N'SELECT @@VERSION;';
```

or

```
EXEC('SELECT @@VERSION;') AT LinkedServer;
```

Yet, when I try to assign that value to a parameter, SQL Server states it's incorrect:

```
SET @DbServerName = (EXEC TMR_DM_LS.[master].sys.sp_executesql N'SELECT @@SERVERNAME')
```

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line XXXX Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line XXXX Incorrect syntax near ')'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
DECLARE @DbServerName sysname;

EXEC [TMR_DM_LS].[master].sys.sp_executesql
   N'SELECT @DbServerName_tmp = @@SERVERNAME;',
   N'@DbServerName_tmp sysname OUTPUT',
   @DbServerName_tmp = @DbServerName OUTPUT;

SELECT @DbServerName AS [RemoteName];
```

**HOWEVER,** the above is how to return info in general. *IF* you are truly only wanting the server name, then I think you already have it on your local server. The Linked Server definition, depending on how it was configured, might very well have the name you are looking for:

```
DECLARE @DbServerName sysname;

SELECT @DbServerName = [data_source]
FROM   sys.servers
WHERE  [name] = N'TMR_DM_LS';

SELECT @DbServerName AS [RemoteName];
```

See if that works before doing the actual remote execution since it would be much more efficient to get the value locally.

**UPDATE**
O.P. replied that the desired value was indeed in the `sys.servers` system catalog view.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it like that because you are returning a result set (via `SELECT`) and not a scalar value. If you wanted to put the result into a variable you could do something like this:

```
DECLARE @version SYSNAME;
DECLARE @params NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @params = '@server_name SYSNAME OUTPUT';
EXEC LinkedServer.[master].sys.sp_executesql
     N'SELECT @version = @@VERSION;',
     @params,
     @version = @version OUTPUT;
SELECT @version;
```

[Using the OUTPUT parameter (sp_executesql)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#c-using-the-output-parameter)

Answer (score 1):

A simple script showing how to [return the server name using openquery](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/115202/22336)

the only difference is that here I put the returning values into variables

```
--first query
--to find out the available linked servers
select * 
from sys.servers
where is_data_access_enabled = 1
  and is_linked = 1

--ckecking it out
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (
         [CTDB12], -- the name here must be one returned from the first query
         'SELECT
             @@SERVERNAME AS TargetServerName,
             SUSER_SNAME() AS ConnectedWith,
             DB_NAME() AS DefaultDB,
             client_net_address AS IPAddress
          FROM
              sys.dm_exec_connections
          WHERE
              session_id = @@SPID
        ')

-- you need to have proper permissions
--OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "CTDB12" returned message "Deferred prepare could not be completed.".
--Msg 297, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
--The user does not have permission to perform this action.


--lets try another server
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY (
         [QG-V-SQLRPL1-PR], -- the name here must be one returned from the first query
         'SELECT
             @@SERVERNAME AS TargetServerName,
             SUSER_SNAME() AS ConnectedWith,
             DB_NAME() AS DefaultDB,
             client_net_address AS IPAddress
          FROM
              sys.dm_exec_connections
          WHERE
              session_id = @@SPID
        ')

--now lets declare variables to keep the info and show them
declare @DbServerName sysname
declare @theuser sysname
declare @IPAddress sysname

SELECT @DbServerName = TargetServerName,
       @theuser = ConnectedWith,
       @IPAddress = IPAddress
FROM OPENQUERY (
         [QG-V-SQLRPL1-PR],  -- the name here must be one returned from the first query
         'SELECT
             @@SERVERNAME AS TargetServerName,
             SUSER_SNAME() AS ConnectedWith,
             DB_NAME() AS DefaultDB,
             client_net_address AS IPAddress
          FROM
              sys.dm_exec_connections
          WHERE
              session_id = @@SPID
        ')


print @DbServerName 
print @theuser 
print @IPAddress
```

[image]